# как сделать чтобы выводил мне других детей из xml файла в tkinter через ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер, tkinter

вот код:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def parseXML(xml_file):
    """
    Парсинг XML используя ElementTree
    """
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=xml_file)
    print(tree.getroot())
    root = tree.getroot()

    print("tag=%s, attrib=%s" % (root.tag, root.attrib))

    for child in root:
        print('child tag',child.tag, child.attrib)
        if child.tag == "appointment":
            for step_child in child:
                print(step_child.tag)


    for child in root:
        print('child tag',child.tag, child.attrib)
        if child.tag == "appointment":
            for step_child in child:
                print(step_child.tag)

def createXML(filename):
    """
    Создаем XML файл.
    """
    root = xml.Element("zAppointments")
    appt = xml.Element("appointment")
    root.append(appt)

    # создаем дочерний суб-элемент. 
    begin = xml.SubElement(appt, "begin")
    begin.text = "1181251680"

    uid = xml.SubElement(appt, "uid")
    uid.text = "040000008200E000"

    alarmTime = xml.SubElement(appt, "alarmTime")
    alarmTime.text = "1181572063"

    state = xml.SubElement(appt, "state")

    location = xml.SubElement(appt, "location")

    duration = xml.SubElement(appt, "duration")
    duration.text = "1800"

    subject = xml.SubElement(appt, "subject")

    tree = xml.ElementTree(root)
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, "r") as fh:
        tree.write(fh)

path_to_program = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Practic"
path_to_XML = os.path.join(path_to_program, 'sss.xcos')

##createXML(path_to_XML)
parseXML(path_to_XML)
```

Comment: Не уж то вы не видели, что вставка кода "как есть" сломало форматирование вопроса? :) В редакторе вопроса есть кнопки форматирования, например `{}`

Comment: Добавьте пример xml. Других детей - это каких?